# Is there anything like Grails taglibs for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, taglib

I have a few months of experience with Ruby on Rails and really loved it from the beginning on. Now, for work, I was asked to code in Grails and although I first had some objections, I now think it's a very decent framework.

One thing that really impressed me in Grails are Taglibs because they make frontend modularity so much easier.

I would really like to do something with Rails.

- Is there anything like Taglibs for Rails?
- If not, what are the best practices for accomplishing this kind of view modularity (and, in essence, making my life easier)?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own helpers and the views can access those helpers. Take as an example [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), which provides extra *methods/tags* to build forms.

Strictly speaking, formtastic is a rails plugin, but it follows the same principles.